# Indesign – screen effect disappears in RBG blend mode

Tags: adobe-indesign, transparency, blend-modes

I have an image that is basically some black lines which I have placed onto a blue background and gave it a screen effect to make it white. This is while in CMYK transparency blend space.

But when I turn it to RBG blend space is disappears.

I know there are ways around this and I have now made jpegs for it and exported them fine. But I just don't understand why it's doing this and if there is a way around it.

I tried turning everything on the page into RGB then applying the effect but the same thing happens.

Any ideas?

Cheers in advance

[image: CMYK Transparency Blend Mode]

[image: Transparency Blend Mode]

Comment: What blend mode are you using? Screen?

Comment: yes. I'm using the Screen effect to make the dashes white.

Comment: I'll ask the obvious... is there some reason you aren't merely using *white* strokes with no blending?